# Passing data from table view to textview of view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I just found a tutorial how to pass data between two table views to textview of ViewController, its nice but I need an app about passing data from just one table view to textview of ViewController, I'm searching about this little problem but can't find it, hope you guys understand me, here is a pic of app tutorial I founded, I uploaded in tiny pic because can't post it here:

[image]

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController{


var FirstTableArray = [String]()

var SecondArray = [SecondTable]()

var ThirdArray = [ThirdView]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    FirstTableArray = ["First", "Second", "Third","Fourth"]


    SecondArray =
        [SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["jdhfhjd","kldjjlkdfjd"]),
            SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["FirstSecond","SecondSecond","ThirdSecond"]),
    SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["FirstThird","SecondThird","ThirdThird"]),
    SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["FirstFourth"])]

    ThirdArray = [ThirdView(ThirdViewArray: [lf1,lf2]),
    ThirdView(ThirdViewArray: ["asdkljf","asdfasd","asdfas"]),
    ThirdView(ThirdViewArray: ["asdkljf","asdfasd","asdfas"]),
    ThirdView(ThirdViewArray: ["asdkljf"])]


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return FirstTableArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    var Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


    Cell.textLabel?.text = FirstTableArray[indexPath.row]

    return Cell

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

    var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController

    var SecondTableArrayTwo : SecondTable

    SecondTableArrayTwo = SecondArray[indexPath.row]

    DestViewController.SecondArray = SecondTableArrayTwo.SecondTitle


    var ThirdAnswerArray : ThirdView

    ThirdAnswerArray = ThirdArray[indexPath.row]

    DestViewController.SecondAnswerArray = ThirdAnswerArray.ThirdViewArray

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your complete Updated code for one `tableView` to `detailView`:

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController{

var FirstTableArray = [String]()
var passThisArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // This array will display on your tableviewcell.
    FirstTableArray = ["First", "Second", "Third","Fourth"]

    //You can pass element of this array
    passThisArray = ["element1", "element2", "element3", "element4"]

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return FirstTableArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    var Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    Cell.textLabel?.text = passThisArray[indexPath.row]

    return Cell

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "detailView") {
        var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController

        //Get the Index of selected Cell
        var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

        //assign string to next view controller instance from selected cell.
        vc.FirstString = FirstTableArray[indexPath.row]
       }
    }
}
```

And you have to modify many things from your project.

And [HERE](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Pass-Data-with-One-Tableview) is your project.

Comment: You can start from here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_456